# TimePicker change to hour and minute selection from code

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Let's say I have TimePicker and I use my fingers to select hour. After I select hour, TimePicker changes layout to 'select minutes'. How do I tell TimePicker, from code, that I want to select hour and not minutes?

Ok, I think I wasn't clear.
When we open TimePicker we select hour(first) and then minutes(second)
We can correct our choice by clicking on hour and minutes TextViews.
How can I change from minutes to hours from code?

Something like:
setHourSelectionLayout();
setMinuteSelectionLayout();

Comment: If you want the users to select only hours, then why don't you use a spinner having values from 1 to 12 instead of a timepicker.

Comment: Oh, man... why can't people just skip the question if they don't know the answer to the ACTUAL question? OP didn't want alternatives or best practices. He wanted to show HOURS again, after the selection is already on minutes. I want that too and I DON'T want not spinners or NumberPickers... So, @justmatt have you been able to do this in the end? (I know it's a long time since)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of case, use a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and keep the minutes constant or dummy set on the TextView/EditText. It will work out for the best